# How to change default DISPLAY environment variable in RHEL8

Tags: rhel, x11, gnome, environment-variables, vnc

I'm in a weird spot in which I'm trying to run an independent vnc server on display localhost:1, but given that I am running Gnome, that display is already being used by the desktop itself.

I do not have the option to use a different display number for my application, unfortunately. Is there a way to have the desktop display mapped to, say, localhost:8 instead?